# Setting up SSH when using different wifi networks?

Tags: wifi, ssh

A bit of a Raspberry Pi newb here, so bear with me! I'm using a Raspberry Pi model 3 for a university project, which means that I hop around different locations and have to get on different WIFI networks. I'm hoping to use SSH to operate my Raspberry Pi on my Lenovo and run code. I believe I'll want to assign the Raspberry Pi a static IP address for the sake of SSH, but am expecting I'll have some issues getting the pi to connect to the right WIFI network immediately. Does anyone have advice on how to go about this? Should I simply bring a monitor with me whenever I use the Pi, and manually select the WIFI network on the Pi?

Or is it a safer bet to simply connect my pi to my laptop via an Ethernet cable every time I plan to use it? That way, I control which network it's connected to and can `ssh` into the pi from there.

Comment: This question is light on details (and could do with some paragraphs and punctuation). Setting a static IP is the ONE thing you shouldn't do.

Comment: Hello and welcome – The ethernet is a good idea AND you can add a wifi dongle/adaptor and connect your laptop to it then connect the built-in wifi to desire SSID manually. All of it is that you are connecting to a new SSID. If you have list about SSIDs which you wanna connect, you can do it with `wpa_supplicant`.

Comment: If you want to connect to different hotspots/networks you cannot use a static ip address.

Answer (score 1):

A few more details would allow more specific answer, but when I do something similar, I use a wifi hotspot/sharing on my phone.  I don't know about iOS, but on Android I can logon to a new network using my phone, then just share this via my phone on a pre-prepared SSID.

If I need a more permanent connection, I can use the access via the hotspot to add a new wpa_supplicant entry for the new network.

In terms of IP addresses, setting up the RPi to use DDNS can be helpful to allow easy access despite network specific IP addresses.